# Piping a string into a cmd does not work in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, pipeline, stdin

I have the following working call when I execute it directly in my PowerShell window:

```
$myexe = "C:\MyExe.exe"
"MyString" | & $myexe // works
Write-Output "MyString" | & $myexe // seems to work too
```

However, when I perform the same in a function of a PowerShell script it does no longer work. The program does not receive the string...any ideas?

Comment: "when I perform the same in a function of a PowerShell script it does no longer work." - can you show us such a script?

Comment: ditto, because as noted below, with just the posted lines in a pristine .ps1, it works as expected, as shown below.

Comment: It's very hard to describe: we realized yesterday that due to the complexity of the script, we overlooked that it executed a different version of the same executable + the maintainers of the executable explicitly removed the feature of piping in data to this executable between those two versions. So that's the actual reason why it doesn't work and why we couldn't provide a suitable example.

Comment: @D.R. It sounds like you figured out the answer to your question. It's probably worth writing that up quickly and accepting it so this question can be marked closed -- and, if you're able to provide more detail, help someone in the same situation down the line. Though even accepting a dupe of your comment is probably helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, **PowerShell does *not* automatically relay pipeline input** received by a given script or function to commands you call from *inside* that script or function.

To do so, you **must use the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input)**<sup>[1]</sup>:

For instance:

```
function foo {
  # Relay the pipeline input received by this function 
  # to an external program, using `cat` as an example.
  $input | & /bin/cat -n # append $args to pass options through
}

'MyString' | foo
```

<sup>Note that `&` is optional in this case, because `/bin/cat` is an unquoted, literal path - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for when `&` is *required*.</sup>

The output (on a Unix-like platform) is:      `1    MyString`, showing that the `cat` utility received the `foo` function's own pipeline input via its stdin, thanks to use of `$input`.

*Without* piping `$input` to `cat`, the latter would receive no stdin input at all (and in the case of `cat` would *block*, waiting for *interactive* input).

If you want to **support passing *filename* arguments too** - in lieu of pipeline input - more work is needed:

```
function foo {
  if ($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) { # Pipeline input present
    # Relay the pipeline input received by this function 
    # to an external program, using `cat` as an example.
    $input | /bin/cat -n $args
  } else { # NO pipeline input.
    /bin/cat -n $args
  }
}

'MyString' | foo  # pipeline input
foo file.txt      # filename argument
```

**Note**:

- Only *non*-[advanced functions and scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) can make use of the `$input` variable, and its use implies that **all input piped to the enclosing function/script is *collected in full, up front*, before sending it on begins**.
- **To truly *stream* a script / function's own pipeline input** to a single invocation of an **external program** - i.e. to relay the input *as it is being received* by the script / function - **requires direct use of .NET APIs**, namely [`System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo) and [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process).

---

<sup>[1] Similarly, `$input` is required to access data piped to a PowerShell command from *outside* PowerShell, via PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh); e.g., from `bash`:

`echo hi | pwsh -c '$input | ForEach-Object { "[{0}]" -f $_ }'`</sup>

Comment: would you happen to have a good example of note number 2, "...requires direct use of .NET APIs"?

Comment: @Gregory, I haven't looked, but I assume that there are C# examples out there. If you have trouble adapting them to PowerShell, I encourage you to ask a new question (feel free to post a link to it here to notify me, once you have done so).

Comment: this was one of the avenues I was trying to chase down here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66270719/4496560 as a third solution to either have a `[cmdlet]`/`[pscmdlet]` object as a `NoteProperty` or to return one back to the pipeline via a `ScriptMethod`, but it just wasn't working out for me

Answer (score 1):

With a simple script that only contains this...

```
$myexe = 'nslookup.exe'
'stackexchange.com' | & $myexe # works
Write-Output 'stackexchange.com' | & $myexe # seems to work too
```

..., it works as expected in the Consolehost/WindowsTerminal as expected.

```
 .\TestExePipe.ps1
# Results
<#
Default Server:  ...
Address:  ...

> Server:  ...
Address:  ...

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    stackexchange.com
Addresses:  151.101.193.69
...

> Default Server:  ...
Address:  ...

> Server:  ...
Address:  ...

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    stackexchange.com
Addresses:  151.101.129.69
          ...

>
#>
```